# How to fill the missing record of Pandas dataframe in pythonic way?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe 'df' like this :

```
         X   Y  
IX1 IX2
A   A1  20  30
    A2  20  30
    A5  20  30
B   B2  20  30
    B4  20  30
```

It lost some rows, and I want to fill in the gap in the middle like this:

```
         X   Y  
IX1 IX2
A   A1  20  30
    A2  20  30
    A3  NaN NaN
    A4  NaN NaN
    A5  20  30
B   B2  20  30
    B3  NaN NaN
    B4  20  30
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this ?

Comment: How would you do it your way?

Comment: For reference, in numpy there's something called a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) to handle cases like this.

Comment: I plan to use 'df.reindex(index= index_mask)', while not figure out how to build 'index_mask' efficiently

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to construct your full index, and then use the `reindex` method of the dataframe. Like so...

```
import pandas
import StringIO
datastring = StringIO.StringIO("""\
C1,C2,C3,C4
A,A1,20,30
A,A2,20,30
A,A5,20,30
B,B2,20,30
B,B4,20,30""")

dataframe = pandas.read_csv(datastring, index_col=['C1', 'C2'])
full_index = [('A', 'A1'), ('A', 'A2'), ('A', 'A3'), 
              ('A', 'A4'), ('A', 'A5'), ('B', 'B1'), 
              ('B', 'B2'), ('B', 'B3'), ('B', 'B4')]
new_df = dataframe.reindex(full_index)
new_df
      C3  C4
A A1  20  30
  A2  20  30
  A3 NaN NaN
  A4 NaN NaN
  A5  20  30
B B1 NaN NaN
  B2  20  30
  B3  20  30
  B4  20  30
```

And then you can use the `fillna` method to set the NaNs to whatever you want.

#### update (June 2014)

Just had to revisit this myself...
In the current version of pandas, there is a function to build `MultiIndex` from the Cartesian product of iterables. So the above solution could become:

```
datastring = StringIO.StringIO("""\
C1,C2,C3,C4
A,1,20,30
A,2,20,30
A,5,20,30
B,2,20,30
B,4,20,30""")

dataframe = pandas.read_csv(datastring, index_col=['C1', 'C2'])
full_index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([('A', 'B'), range(6)], names=['C1', 'C2'])
new_df = dataframe.reindex(full_index)
new_df
      C3  C4
C1 C2
 A  1  20  30
    2  20  30
    3 NaN NaN
    4 NaN NaN
    5  20  30
 B  1 NaN NaN
    2  20  30
    3  20  30
    4  20  30
    5 NaN NaN
```

Pretty elegant, in my opinion.

Comment: I think you might want something more like this (sorry, comment does not work with newlines):
`
import StringIO
datastring = StringIO.StringIO("""\
C1,C2,C3,C4
A,1,20,30
A,2,20,30
A,5,20,30
B,2,20,30
B,4,20,30""")

df = pd.read_csv(datastring, index_col=['C1', 'C2'])
display(df)
full_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('A', 'B'), range(6)], names=['C1', 'C2'])
display(full_index)

new_df = df.reindex(full_index)
display(new_df)`

Comment: Awesome answer.  `(range(6)` should be changed to `range(6)` though.

Comment: One more thing: In your second example, you should change the C2 column values in the original dataframe to [1, 2, 5...] instead of [A1, A2, A5...]. As is, reindexing leads to a df full of NaNs.