# Filling a pandas dataframe column with data between two indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

| event | job_id_num |
| --- | --- |
| JOB_START | 12345 |
| --- | --- |
| JOB_END | 12345 |
| RETOOL | 99999 |
| JOB_START | 12346 |
| --- | --- |
| JOB_END | 12346 |

Between the `JOB_START` and `JOB_END` events there can be `x` number of rows depending on what job steps take place for a given job.  The `JOB_START` and `JOB_END` events are marked with the job_id_number, but the rows between are not.  I need to fill the rows in between the existing `job_id_nums`.

I started  [with this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181761/filling-in-missing-data-in-pandas-dataframe), but this solution is for a multi-index Dataframe, whereas mine is not.  I can `ffill()` the values in I need, but I have to know how many rows I need to fill in as the number of rows to be filled will change `job_id_num` to `job_id_num`.

Comment: I'm not sure why `ffill` wouldn't work. It doesn't need the number of rows to fill. Are you saying *you* need to know how many rows are there?

Comment: Can you post the sample dataframe including the missing rows?

Comment: @MustafaAydın I seem to only be able to ffill for 1 row after the first occurance of a `job_id_num` .  The other x rows between the `job_id_num` are still left unfilled, so if there are 10 rows to be filled, 1 gets filled, the other 9 do not.

Comment: @Nk03 I lead this post off with a very small sample!  Or am I missing something in your ask?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  `.ffill()` will not work if the column data is an empty string `''`, it needs `NaN`.  Once I converted empty strings to `NaN` the rows I wanted filled were filled.