# Re-index to insert missing rows in a multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a MultiIndexed DataFrame with three levels of indices. I would like to expand my third level to contain all values in a given range, but only for the existing values in the two upper levels. 
For example, assume the first level is name, the second level is date and the third level is hour. I would like to have rows for all 24 possible hours (even if some are currently missing), but only for the already existing names and dates. The values in new rows can be filled with zeros.

So a simple example input would be:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,3],[2,2,1,4], [3,3,2,5]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C','val'])
>>> df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
>>> df
       val
A B C     
1 1 1    3
2 2 1    4
3 3 2    5
```

if the required values for C are [1,2,3], the desired output would be:

```
       val
A B C     
1 1 1    3
    2    0
    3    0
2 2 1    4
    2    0
    3    0
3 3 1    0
    2    5
    3    0
```

I know how to achieve this using groupby and applying a defined function for each group, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing this with reindex (I couldn't make this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856941/insert-0-values-for-missing-dates-within-multiindex) work for a MultiIndex case, but perhaps I'm missing something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
partial_indices = [ i[0:2] for i in df.index.values ]
C_reqd = [1, 2, 3]
final_indices = [j+(i,) for j in partial_indices for i in C_reqd]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(final_indices, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(0, index), columns=['val'])
df2.update(df)
```

**Output**

```
df2
       val
A B C
1 1 1  3.0
    2  0.0
    3  0.0
2 2 1  4.0
    2  0.0
    3  0.0
3 3 1  0.0
    2  5.0
    3  0.0
```

Comment: nice, thank you! (Can't upvote with my reputation yet)