# Reindex from MultiIndex removes row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a case where I have a dataset that I am trying to fill in missing dates for each value in the categorical column I am additionally grouping by data. I was following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856941/insert-0-values-for-missing-dates-within-multiindex), and at the point where I reindex the cartesian product, I see that all row values for `ap` and `qps` columns (Non-indexed) are now NaN. I'm curious where I might have gone wrong with trying to use this solution? Is there something I missed with re-indexing?

**Issues in question:**

```
new_dma_values_df = dma_values_groupby.reindex(new_index)

created_at (Level 1) | dma_description (Level 2) | ap | qps
2021-01-01 | ALBANY - SCHENECTADY - TROY | NaN | NaN
...
```

**Full Code:**

```
dma_values_groupby.columns
Index(['created_at', 'dma_description', 'ap', 'qps'], dtype='object')


idx = pd.period_range(min(dma_values_groupby['created_at']), max(dma_values_groupby['created_at']))

PeriodIndex(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04',
             '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06', '2022-01-07', '2022-01-08',
             '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10',
             ...
             '2022-12-13', '2022-12-14', '2022-12-15', '2022-12-16',
             '2022-12-17', '2022-12-18', '2022-12-19', '2022-12-20',
             '2022-12-21', '2022-12-22'],
            dtype='period[D]', length=356)

dma_values_groupby.set_index(['created_at', 'dma_description'], inplace=True)

dma_values_groupby.head(5)

created_at (Level 1) | dma_description (Level 2) | ap | qps
2021-01-01 | ALBANY - SCHENECTADY - TROY | 3 | 1
...

(created_at_index, dma_description_index) = dma_values_groupby.index.levels

new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([idx, dma_description_index])

new_index

MultiIndex([('2022-01-01',             'ABILENE - SWEETWATER'),
            ('2022-01-01',      'ALBANY - SCHENECTADY - TROY'),
            ('2022-01-01',                       'ALBANY, GA'),
            ...
           names=[None, 'dma_description'], length=72268)

new_dma_values_df = dma_values_groupby.reindex(new_index)

created_at (Level 1) | dma_description (Level 2) | ap | qps
2021-01-01 | ALBANY - SCHENECTADY - TROY | NaN | NaN
...

new_dma_values_df = new_dma_values_df.fillna(0).astype(int) # Value I plan to use after the fix
```

Comment: Good question; if there are lots of / only nans left over in your data after reindexing, then there must have been no overlap between the old and new index. Are you sure that the old index had dtype `period` for the dates? Maybe they were `str` or `datetime64` instead.

Comment: PS: reindex also has kwarg `fill_value`, which might save you the final explicit call to `fillna` and `astype`.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs yes the dtype for `created_at` was `datetime64`. I thought that type was necessary prior to setting the index. Is there a different value that should have been used?

Comment: `datetime64` is perfectly fine. In that case, instead of using `period_range`, try using `date_range` when you create the set of dates you use to build the multi index with

Comment: That was the fix! I should have realized that the dtypes need to be the same. Thank you!