# how to skip a row in pandas dataframe group by cumsum function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use cumsum() to get the result of I want in pandas, but I'm stuck.

```
        score1  score2
team slot       
a   2   4   6
a   3   3   7
a   4   2   1
a   5   4   3
b   1   7   2
b   2   2   10
b   5   1   9
```

my original data look like above , I want to do cummulative of score1 and score2 group by team and slot. I used

```
df= df.groupby(by=['team','slot']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()
```

this code above almost got I want , but each team needs exactly 5 slot like output below , how can I fix this issue ?

[image]

Comment: reindex your output per the final version of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390336/how-to-fill-the-missing-record-of-pandas-dataframe-in-pythonic-way/13297472#13297472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Paul H commented, here is the code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

text = """team slot  score1  score2
a   2   4   6
a   3   3   7
a   4   2   1
a   5   4   3
b   1   7   2
b   2   2   10
b   5   1   9
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(text), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=[0, 1])
df2 = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], range(1, 6)]))
df2.fillna(0).groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()
```